# Add dynamic value in SQL Pivot

Tags: sql-server-2012

I want to pass the values dynamically in PIVOT. Please review the following code and I got the error - Must declare the scalar variable "@empid". Please help me...

```
declare @empid nvarchar(20), @fromdate date, @todate date, @cols nvarchar(max), @query nvarchar(max)
set @empid = 'EC0100'
set @fromdate = '10/01/13'
set @todate = '10/31/13'

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c._Date) 
        FROM MIS_BM_Calendar c
        where c._Date between @fromdate and @todate
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'select * from
(
select  e.UserName, c._Date ,SUM(DATEDIFF(SS,0,c.TimeTaken)) As TimeTaken from MIS_BM_Users e 
inner join MIS_Opus c on 
e.EmpId=c.EmpId 
where e.TeamLeaderID=@empid and c._Date between @fromdate and @todate
group by c._Date, e.UserName
) As SourceTable
Pivot
(
SUM(TimeTaken) for _Date In ('+ @cols +') As Pvt'

execute(@query)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found it myself. Here is the correct code...

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[MIS_AccountReport] ( @AccountManagerId nvarchar(20), @Startdate datetime, @Enddate datetime, @Condition1 nvarchar(20),@condition2 nvarchar(20)
)
As
Begin
declare  @cols nvarchar(max), @query  AS VARCHAR(MAX), @hr nvarchar(10), @min nvarchar(10) set @hr='Hr(s)'
set @min='Min(s)'

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(convert(nvarchar(20),c._Date, 101))
         FROM MIS_BM_Calendar c
         where c._Date between @Startdate and @Enddate
         FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
         ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
     ,1,1,'')



set @query= 'select UserName, '+@cols+' from
(
select  e.UserName, c._Date ,SUM(DATEDIFF(SS,0,c.TimeTaken))  As 
TimeTaken from MIS_BM_Users e
inner join MIS_Opus c on e.EmpId=c.EmpId
where (e.AccountManagerID='''+@AccountManagerId+''')
and c.Category not in ('''+@Condition1+''', '''+@condition2+''')
group by c._Date, e.UserName
) As SourceTable
Pivot
(
SUM(TimeTaken) for _Date in ('+@cols+')
) As Pvt'

execute(@query)
End
```